# Filter child of parent elements in isotope

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I using isotope to filter data.

Currently, I have an HTML with the struct like:

```js
jQuery('.container-filter-cate').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.list-posts',
  filter: ':nth-child(-n+3)'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <li><a href="" data-filter="*">All Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-filter=".sport">Sport</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-filter=".cinema">Cinema</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-filter=".music">Music</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="container-filter-cate">
    <ul class="list-posts sport">
        <li>Text 1</li>
        <li>Text 2</li>
        <li>Text 3</li>
        <li>Text 4</li>
    </ul>
    
    <ul class="list-posts cinema">
        <li>Text 5</li>
        <li>Text 6</li>
    </ul>
    
    <ul class="list-posts music">
        <li>Text 7</li>
        <li>Text 8</li>
        <li>Text 9</li>
        <li>Text 10</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want it should be filtered with `<li>` tag instead of `ul` like current.

I tried to with:

`filter: 'ul.list-posts li:nth-child(-n+2)'`

but it's not working.

**Edited:** [my fiddle at here](http://jsfiddle.net/DA3wF/312/)

My purpose is using `filter` to limit item to show.

You can change values of `filter: ':nth-child(-n+3)'` to see more information.

When I change to values of `filter: ':nth-child(-n+2)'` the result will be shown: first and second `ul`.

If first `ul` contain 5 items, second `ul` contain 40 items, it also shows 45 items.

Will fail because I only want 2 item to appear, not all items of two `ul`.

Comment: You can create JSFIDDLE for the same, wont take much time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this,

HTML CODE,

```
<ul id='oiso'>
  <li><a href="javascript:;" data-filter="*">All Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;" data-filter=".sport">sport</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;" data-filter=".cinema">cinema</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;" data-filter=".music">music</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="container-filter-cate">
  <ul class="list-posts sport">
    <li>Text 1</li>
    <li>Text 2</li>
    <li>Text 3</li>
    <li>Text 4</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="list-posts cinema">
    <li>Text 5</li>
    <li>Text 6</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="list-posts music">
    <li>Text 7</li>
    <li>Text 8</li>
    <li>Text 9</li>
    <li>Text 10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS CODE

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $container = $('.list-posts');
  $container.isotope({});
  $('#oiso li a').on('click', function() {
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({
      filter: $(selector).find("li")
    });
    return false;
  });
})
```

For more details once visit jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/DA3wF/314/)